# Bootstrap assistance - trying to create a 2 column table using list-group-item

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Beginner coder requesting a little help with bootstrap4.

I'm trying to create a list group item for displaying user reviews.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOgZd.jpg)

I've tried tinkering every thing I can think of.

On the face of it, it seems like it should be really simple, but I'm stumped.

Would love to know what you think? Do I need specific css to do it?

```
<div class="panel-heading">
    <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="list-group">
    {% if comments %}
    {% for comment in comments %}
    <div class="list-group-item ">
    <!--left hand side of table to store username, userstatus and userimage -->
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-xl-2">
        <div class="col-lg-12" align="center">
        <p><a href="{% url 'profile' comment.user %}">{{ comment.user }}</a></p>
        </div>
            <div class="col-lg-12" align="center">
            <p class="status">({{ comment.user.status }})</p>
            </div>
            <div>
            <img class="rounded mx-auto d-block" width="64" height="64" src="{{ MEDIA_URL}}{{ comment.user.picture }}"/><p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--right hand side of table to store date comment posted and comment -->
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-xl-8">
            <div class="col-lg-12" align="left">
        <p>Posted: {{ comment.created}}</p>
        </div>          
        <div>
        <p>{{comment.body}}</p>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
        {% else %}
        <p>There are no comments</p>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There are no panels in Bootstrap 4

Comment: ah ok, I'm following the tango with django book. Do you mind if I ask what you recommend go in it's place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap now recommend that you use their Cards content container instead of using panels. To keep certain elements on the same line, you should keep those elements within the same row.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="card">
  <div class="card-body">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <a href="#">0808148w</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <p class="status">Current student</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <p>Posted: 20/03/2019</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <img class="rounded d-block" width="64" height="64" src="https://picsum.photos/64/?random" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-10 card-text">
        Comments...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="card">
  <div class="card-body">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <a href="#">0808148w</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <p class="status">Current student</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <p>Posted: 21/03/2019</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <img class="rounded d-block" width="64" height="64" src="https://picsum.photos/64/?random" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-10 card-text">
        Comments...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```